# Reversing a stack using queue in C

Tags: c, stack, queue, reverse

I need to reverse a stack using queue. The reverseStack() function only uses push()and pop()when adding or removing integers from the stack, and only uses enqueue() and dequeue()  when adding or removing integers from the queue.

But I got a segmentation fault at `push(&s, dequeue(&q));`.
Could anyone tell me what does this mean? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
void reverseStack(Stack *s) 
{
    Queue *q;

    while(!isEmptyStack(s)) //pop items from stack and queue into q
    {
        enqueue(&q, pop(s));
    }
    while(!isEmptyQueue(q)) //dequeue items from queue and push to stack
    {
        push(&s, dequeue(&q));
    }
}
```

Updated:

```
typedef struct _listnode{
   int item;
   struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode;

typedef struct _linkedlist{
   int size;
   ListNode *head;
   ListNode *tail;
} LinkedList;

////////////////////////////////// stack    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef struct stack{
    LinkedList ll;
} Stack;

//////////////////////////////////// queue ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

typedef struct _queue{
    LinkedList ll;
} Queue;
```

I was given these list of functions and I need to create the reverseStack() function based on these.

```
void push(Stack *s, int item){
   insertNode(&(s->ll), 0, item);
}

int pop(Stack *s){
   int item;
   if(!isEmptyStack(s)){
    item = ((s->ll).head)->item;
    removeNode(&(s->ll), 0);
    return item;
   }
    return INT_MIN;
}

int peek(Stack *s){
   return ((s->ll).head)->item;
}

int isEmptyStack(Stack *s){
   if ((s->ll).size == 0)
      return 1;
   return 0;
}

void enqueue(Queue *q, int item){
   insertNode(&(q->ll), q->ll.size, item);
}

int dequeue(Queue *q){
   int item;
   item = ((q->ll).head)->item;
   removeNode(&(q->ll), 0);
   return item;
}

int isEmptyQueue(Queue *q){
   if ((q->ll).size == 0)
      return 1;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for push()?

Comment: Load your program with the debugger and single-step. If you don't know how to use the debugger, now is the perfect time to learn. It will save you a whole bunch of time.

Comment: Hello, thought I would just give my input. The answer provided by OP was already 90% there. The concept is already correct. The only thing wrong is just the declaration of the Queue. Just add these lines and the problem is solved: 

Queue q;
q.ll.head =NULL;
q.ll.size =0;

Answer (score -1):

There are several problems here.

Your `reverseStack` method is:

```
void reverseStack(Stack *s) 
{
    Queue *q;

    while(!isEmptyStack(s)) //pop items from stack and queue into q
    {
        enqueue(&q, pop(s));
    }
    while(!isEmptyQueue(q)) //dequeue items from queue and push to stack
    {
        push(&s, dequeue(&q));
    }
}
```

Here, you *declare* `q`, but you never *define* it. The first thing you need to do is make `q` point to something, or perhaps you meant to write:

```
Queue q;
```

Which would allocate space for a `Queue` structure on the processor stack.

With the code as written, I don't understand how it works. The calls to `enqueue` should die because `q` is never assigned a value. Although I guess it's possible, C being the friendly language it is, that since you're passing the *address* of `q` rather than the *value* of `q`, you're just corrupting the call stack.

In any event, unless you fix that (either make `q` a non-pointer, or assign it a value by calling `malloc`), you're going to have problems. If it really is supposed to be dynamically allocated, then replace `&q` with `q` in that function.

Your `push` is defined as:

```
void push(Stack *s, int item){
   insertNode(&(s->ll), 0, item);
}
```

That says you need to pass a `Stack *` (pointer to a stack) as the first parameter.

But in your `reverseStack` function, `s` is already a `Stack *` (pointer to a stack). But you're calling `push` with the address of the pointer. You're passing a `Stack **` (pointer-to-pointer to stack).

The correct call would be:

```
push(s, dequeue(q)); // or maybe dequeue(&q), depending on how you
                     // you end up defining q.
```

Your C compiler should have given you errors on those lines. Or ... well, C being what it is, perhaps it just gave you warnings.

A compiler warning is nothing more than an error in disguise. Compile with the highest possible warning level, enable the "warnings as errors" option, and *fix every warning*.

Comment: Hey, downvoter: let me know what's wrong with this answer, so I can fix it.