# Refering to queue as pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am fairly new to C and is confused by the concept of pointers.
I have wrote two different sets of codes and only one work and I wonder what is the problem.

```
    void reverseStack(Stack *s)
{
    /* add your code here */
    Queue *q;
    q->ll.head = NULL;
    q->ll.tail = NULL;
    q->ll.size = 0;
    

    while(!(isEmptyStack(s))){
        
        enqueue(q,pop(s));
        
    }
    
    while(!(isEmptyQueue(q))){
        push(s,dequeue(q));
       
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

the above doesnt work when i refer to the queue as a pointer
edit:return segfault

```
    void reverseStack(Stack *s)
{
    /* add your code here */
    Queue q;
    q.ll.head = NULL;
    q.ll.tail = NULL;
    q.ll.size = 0;
    

    while(!(isEmptyStack(s))){
        
        enqueue(&q,pop(s));
        
    }
    
    while(!(isEmptyQueue(&q))){
        push(s,dequeue(&q));
       
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

This ,however, works.
edit:returns reversed stack

Isnt both code the same functionality wise? Why the difference in result though?

Side Note: the functions I was given in this program is similar to the functions listed in this question
[Reversing a stack using queue in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58662135/reversing-a-stack-using-queue-in-c)

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a problem description. You should explain what input you give, exactly what output you want, and what output you get instead.

Comment: Take inspiration from the source code of *existing* open source software coded in C, such as [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/). They all have [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) sometimes used as queues. Compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never allocated a Queue for `q` to point at!  It's just pointing at random memory, and will likely result in a segfault if you attempt to use it.  You have to assign something to it.

You can either allocate one statically or dynamically.

static:

```
Queue staticQueue;
Queue *q = &staticQueue;
```

dynamic:

```
Queue *q = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
```

Note: if you use `staticQueue`, you can't return the pointer because the queue will be deleted when the function returns.  If you use the dynamic, remember to `free()` it when you're done!

Comment: i get ur idea. but if the defining queue part is the problem doesnt it mean that both the code shouldnt work at all?

Comment: @sventan Declaring a variable in a function is declaring space for it.  So `int a` and `Queue q` make enough room for an int and a Queue, respectively.  `Queue *q` however, makes enough room for a pointer (4 or 8 bytes) which is just a fancy integer, which holds the memory address of something.  So, you have to set it to point at something.  Otherwise it starts as `zero` or an `undefined number` depending where you create it.

Comment: ah i see now. thks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't both code the same functionality wise?

From your assumption, yes. But the first example uses a pointer. You can dynamically allocate more than one room for it to store multiple `Queue` together. However, you can only store a single value at a time in the second example.

> Why the difference in result though?

You haven't allocated sufficient memory to point at that tends to undefined-behavior. As long as you need only a single struct of Queue at a time, the second program suffices your demand. Still, things are different. Using pointers enables you to store multiple `Queue` in a single pointer, which is obviously not possible without a pointer.